# UITableViewAutomaticDimension Not Working for Resizing Cell Height

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

My cell displays fine as long as I don't try to enable the automatic resizing. When I add the two lines for auto-resizing in my viewController, everything under the profile picture, username, and date disappears (the cell is supposed to look like Instagram does when you click on a picture).

If I comment out `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 450`then the cell displays exactly like it is supposed to, but it obviously doesn't resize.

This is the code I have currently:
In my tableViewController:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 450
```

In my cellViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var profilePic: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var mainPic: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var likeBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var commentBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var moreBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var likeLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var uuidLbl: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    //allow constraints
    profilePic.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    usernameBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dateLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    mainPic.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    likeBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    commentBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    moreBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    likeLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    uuidLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let pictureWidth = width - 20

    //constraints
    //vertical constraints: objects that are directly above or below each other are in same constraint, if not vertical it must go in another constraint
    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        //V: = vertical constraint ; | = top border ; -5-[profilePic(30)] make profilePic with height of 30 and place 5 points below top border ; -10-[mainPic(\(pictureWidth))] make pic with height of pictureWidth and place 10 points below profilePic ; -5-[like(30)] make like button height 30 points and put 5 points below mainPic
        withVisualFormat: "V:|-10-[profilePic(30)]-10-[mainPic(\(pictureWidth))]-5-[like(30)]-5-[title]",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["profilePic":profilePic, "mainPic":mainPic, "like":likeBtn, "title":titleLbl]))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        //place username 5 points below top border
        withVisualFormat: "V:|-10-[username]",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["username": usernameBtn]))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        //place comment button 10 points below mainPic
        withVisualFormat: "V:[mainPic]-5-[comment]",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["mainPic":mainPic, "comment":commentBtn]))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|-10-[date]",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["date":dateLbl]))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:[mainPic]-10-[likes]",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["mainPic":mainPic, "likes":likeLbl]))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:[mainPic]-5-[more]",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["mainPic":mainPic, "more":moreBtn]))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[profilePic(30)]-10-[username]-10-|",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["profilePic":profilePic, "username":usernameBtn]))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[mainPic]-10-|",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["mainPic":mainPic]))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|-15-[like(30)]-10-[likes]-30-[comment]",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["like":likeBtn, "likes":likeLbl, "comment":commentBtn]))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:[more]-15-|",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["more":moreBtn]))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|-15-[title]-15-|",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["title":titleLbl]))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:[date]-10-|",
        options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["date":dateLbl]))
```

}
}

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your pictures are not working

Comment: Is your tableView created programmically.i have a trouble seeing picture on the link you posted.can you upload a pic stright into your post...?

Comment: I just updated my code on method 2.try it should work...

Comment: Sorry it took so long to update. I put the pics in the question now

Comment: Those two solutions still aren't working. Whenever I implement them I lose the image (like in pic2 above).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

**Note:** Both method should work.Tested in Swift 3.

Method 1:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 // standard tableViewCell height
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

 return yourArrayName.count
 }
```

Method 2:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 // standard tableViewCell height
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

 return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
 return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }
```

**Note:** You may need to put this code inside your cellForRowAt

```
    yourCellName.sizeToFit()
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: When I include any of your code it just causes everything under the username to disappear. I added pictures to the original question

Comment: I support this answer. But sometimes you *also* need to put everything inside a container view *inside* the cell's default view, auto-layout constrain the views borders to the cell's views, and place its contents inside normally, but have the height be set by the contents not a height constraint