# Ios swift TableView Cell Label LineBreak not working ...

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, line-breaks, custom-cell

I am new to IOS development. I am facing an issue regarding Linebreak in end of label. I have set tableview cell label linebreak as Truncate Tail but its not working (not replacing end with three dots). Kindly guide my that how can I resolve this issue.
Thank You

[No three dots are showing as LineBreak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toDQf.png)

[On Drag Left Label Text is overlaping the action buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuHOf.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. Please post code as text, not as image. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: what are the constraints that you are adding to the label? are you determining its width (by adding leading a trailing to it)?

Comment: Make sure you auto constraints to your label first  and check my answer  in this post may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293336/uitableviewautomaticdimension-not-working-for-resizing-cell-height/40300589#40300589

Comment: @Joe Thank you too Joe and Ahmad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Click 'Resolve Auto Layout constraints' and then click Update Layout Constraints. It will appear popup then add height and width constraints.
You will see issue will be resolved.

Comment: yeah thats worked. Thank You soo much

Answer (score 1):

You have given `cell.eventName.numberOfLines = 0` , this means it will wrap your text in multiple line. It will not truncate it. You need to give default `numberOfLines`(i.e. 1) to get the three dots at the end.

Comment: Hi @Sharpkits, I have changed cell.eventName.numberOfLines to 1. but result remains same even I remove this line no effect no result.

Comment: May be width of your eventName label is going out of your screen as observed from screenshots. Layout of label is not set properly.