# How can I resize a label within a table cell without reloading table?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a table and the cells have a label and I want to be able to update a label directly without reloading the table or cell.  I found a way to do this and it works:

```
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)) as! cellClass
     cell.textLabel.text = newText as? String
```

The only problem is that the size of the label doesn't change.  If you reload the table, the label changes size to adapt to the amount of text.  I tried using layoutIfNeeded() and sizeToFit() but the label won't extend to a second row.  The width isn't a big deal, it's mostly that it doesn't wrap, so in other words the height won't extend for more lines.

Comment: Also like at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293336/uitableviewautomaticdimension-not-working-for-resizing-cell-height/40300589#40300589

Comment: Have you tried `tableView.beginUpdates()` followed by `tableView.endUpdates()`?

Comment: there's something to the beginUpdates/endUpdates thing.  It is doing what I want, but the problem is that sometimes this label gets updated quickly and it seems to be crashing when that happens.  For an update or two, it works though.  I tried getting main queue but still crashing. Any idea why it's doing this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would recommend to create a custom cell (a subclass of UITableViewCell), and name that UILabel something different, say articleTitleLabel (depending on your context). "textLabel" is an inherited property, and I guess you could still use that, but make sure you customize it inside "awakeFromNib" method (set numberOfLines = 0, or 2). I would also recommend to add a public instance method inside the custom cell class. Something like this:

```
function configureWithText(text: String) {
    articleTitleLabel.text = text
    // or, textLabel.text = text
}
```

Also, you may need to create a .xib file for the custom cell, and set some Top, Bottom, Left and Right constraints to your label.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Didn't work.  I'm already doing most of these things, and added a function instead of changing the text directly but it does the same thing.