# TableViewCell Auto height issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I am writing an iOS app. 
User types in movie search keywords and it fetches data from omdbapi.com and displays movies in tableview.
Issue is that that table view cell isn't getting displayed correctly.

Project URL:
[project on onedrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AJiCkv5jWoLeitcx)

I tried using every autolayout method but, its not working.

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    }
```

Comment: check this post will helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293336/uitableviewautomaticdimension-not-working-for-resizing-cell-height/40300589#40300589

Comment: could you post your result image@Atif Shabeer

Comment: Check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43556505/3236890

Answer (score 0):

You need to set estimate method for table height too. so place these method for height calculation and also check your cell constraint.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Hope this will help you.