# How to create dynamic cell in tableview (without custom cell)?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created `UITableView` with default `cell.imagview`, `cell.textLabel` and `cell.detailTextLabel.text`.
I want to set cell dynamic according to content. I am able to set it dynamic only for either `TextLabel` or `detailTextLabel`. But to for both at same time.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: create custom cell class of type UITableViewCell.

Comment: is this possible without using custom cell?

Comment: @ sss i am not getting your question correctly do you want height of cell to be dynamic according to label text?If yes read this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: you have to set Constraints for both labels and and then set estimateRowheight and Row height in viewdidload or Just create Custom cell

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43556505/3236890 ,

Comment: yes I want dynamic height according to content in both TextLabel and detailTextLabel..which is not custom so I can no t set constraint....tableview is programatic

Comment: The built-in cell types have labels set to 1 line only, so in order to use dynamic height based on content in the labels requires you to write code to "customize" those elements - so you are, in essence, using a custom cell already. Why are you opposed to that?

Answer (score 0):

@sss You need to return height of every cell in datasource method heightForCell at index path. so You need to calculate the height of the cell in that datasource method for every index path.

Comment: Can you please explain how can I calculate height ?