# UITableView Dynamic Cell Height when we have 3 or more Data Source with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've 3-5 dataSource and in ViewDidLoad() I've mentioned the property for dynamic cell height:-

```
  [self.tableView setEstimatedRowHeight:40.0];
  [self.tableView setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
```

but the tableview don't update accordingly.. first two-three cell shows contents in good way but as soon as I scroll the tableview, cell gets compressed and then cell shows half of the content.

**UPDATED**

screen of customCell is
[tableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqjJI.png)
andConstraints Are:[tableViewCellConstraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0xou.png)
I have a UIView in cell and label and a uiimageview inside the view

**More Update::**

I think its coz i'm also using an empty cell to have a space between two cell and in the delegate method for i doing this

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 20.0;
}

 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row %2 == 0) {
    return 15;
}
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Use customcells.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43556505/3236890 this may help

Comment: I dont think number of Datasource has any effect on cells height. AutomaticDimension will work if the components either have intrinsic sizes or have height constraints set. I believe you are messing up with autolayout constraints hence cell is compressed. Post the cell xib with constraint. Will let u know the issue

Comment: have a look to updated post.. I've mentioned the details

Comment: uiview constraints are:: Top,Bottom,Trailing and Leading 0 to cell contentview

Comment: @NavanindraVats What are the constraints that are given for the divider UIImageView?

Comment: for that its leading trailing and botton to 0 with height 3

Comment: need more opinion on the updated post... please consider **more Updates** empty cell are loaded at even index

Comment: after going through the various post and the one linked in the comment.. I'm getting this warning::

[Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.