# Changing UITableViewCell height depending on size of UILabel subview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I'm making a simple texting app for practice and the UITableView has lots of cells containing messages.

[image: Texting App]

It works well with one-line messages but, as you can see on the bottom, with multi-line texts the size of the UITableViewCell starts getting in the way and cutting the message short. Just in case, here's the code for my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if usernames[indexPath.row] == PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("text")!
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reply")!
        (cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel).text = usernames[indexPath.row]
    }
    (cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel).text = messages[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Basically I just need a solution that will enable this app to support multi-line messages. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: did you use UITableViewAutomaticDimension ?

Comment: No I'm not even sure what that is

Comment: check  this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40300589/3901620

Comment: r u using autolayout or else for UI

Comment: Yes I'm using autolayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you need to do:

1) In `viewDidLoad`, specify these:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
# The estimated row height number is not that important, just approximate it
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

2) Define all constraints for your custom cell. Make sure top and bottom constraints specifically are defined.

The second step is particularly important.

Comment: Ok I'll try this

Comment: Got this error: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.

Comment: Did you place your views inside the content view first, then set the constraints?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way I know how to do it

Comment: Never mind, I actually saw the second step now and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one thing though, I am still getting the error that I got before

Comment: you are getting error but your problem is solved right?

Answer (score 1):

1) On Storyboard,
   In Attribute Inspector section.
   Set Lines = 0

2) In func viewDidLoad(),

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use self-sizing table view cells and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. [This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) is quite good article about it.

> The trick to getting Auto Layout to work on a UITableViewCell is to ensure you have constraints to pin each subview on all sides — that is, each subview should have leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints. Then, the intrinsic height of the subviews will be used to dictate the height of each cell. You’ll do this now.

Then setup rowHeight to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```